# XML default namespace and XSLT transfornation trouble in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, transformation, xml-namespaces

In P.S. of this posting you can find a C# code snippet, which uses XSLT transformation + RegEx matching to get currency rate value from an XML document. Please read my question inline quoted by

//+

...

//-

comment lines group.

Thank you.

P.S. Code:

```
   string currencyCode = "RUB";
var xml = new StringReader( 
    @"<gesmes:Envelope 
        xmlns:gesmes='http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01' 
        xmlns{{EmptyNameSpace}} ='http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref'>
        <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
        <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time='2012-06-27'>
        <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.2478' />
        <Cube currency='RUB' rate='41.1252' />
        <Cube currency='ZAR' rate='10.4601' />
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
    </gesmes:Envelope>"
            .Replace("{{EmptyNameSpace}}", ":ns1")
            //+
            // I'd like to get this code working the same way as it does now
            // producing
            //
            // Result: EUR/RUB => 41.1252
            //
            // output but when the above code line will be commented
            // and the below code line uncommented
            //-
            //.Replace("{{EmptyNameSpace}}", "") 
);

var xslt = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(
@"<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0' 
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
    xmlns:gesmes='http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01' 
    xmlns:ns1 ='http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref'
    >

<xsl:variable name='x1' select='gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube[@currency=""{0}""]' />
<xsl:template match='gesmes:Envelope'>
  [<xsl:apply-templates select='$x1' />]
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='Cube'>
    <xsl:value-of select='@rate' />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>".Replace("{0}", currencyCode)  

));

var xDoc = new XPathDocument(xml);
var xTr = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform(); 
xTr.Load(xslt) ;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb); 
xTr.Transform(xDoc, null, writer);

string pattern = @"\[(?'name'[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)\]";

System.Console.WriteLine(
    "Result: EUR/{0} => {1}",
    currencyCode, 
    Regex.Match(sb.ToString(), pattern)
   .Groups["name"].Value);    

// Result: EUR/RUB => 41.1252
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from looking at that code, your problems is handling the default namespace in XPath:

- As long as `{{EmptyNameSpace}}` is `:ns1`, everything's fine - in your Xml document, the namespaces `http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01` and `http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref` with the prefixes `gesmes` and `ns1` are defined; your Xml document uses identifiers such as `<gesmes:Envelope>` from `gesmes` and others, namely `<Cube>`, that are not associated with any namespace. In the XSLT code, you are using XPath expressions, such as (here shortened) `gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube`, which is fine, as this expression refers to an `<Envelope>` element from the namespace declared with the `gesmes` prefix, as well as to `<Cube>` elements without a namespace.
- Once you set `{{EmptyNameSpace}}` to an empty string, this changes: Now, `http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref` is the default namespace of your document. Hence, the `<Cube>` elements in your document are considered to belong to that namespace. Your XPath expression, however, still considers the `<Cube>` elements that appear in the XPath as having no namespace - they do not have any namespace prefix and XPath doesn't know about default namespaces.

As a solution, you should add namespace prefixes to your XPath expression - if the `<Cube>` elements belong to the `http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref` namespace, your XPath should read like this:

```
gesmes:Envelope/ns1:Cube/ns1:Cube/ns1:Cube
```

(Of course, the other XPath expressions in your XSLT have to be adapted accordingly.)

Please let me know if you need any further explanations on this - or whether I've gotten on the wrong track with my assumptions.

**Update:** Here's what the XSLT should look like in order to work if the Xml document has the default namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:gesmes='http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01' xmlns:ns1='http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref'>

    <xsl:variable name='x1' select='gesmes:Envelope/ns1:Cube/ns1:Cube/ns1:Cube[@currency="RUB"]'/>

    <xsl:template match='gesmes:Envelope'>
        [<xsl:apply-templates select='$x1'/>]
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='ns1:Cube'>
        <xsl:value-of select='@rate'/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I make `http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref` a default namespace by setting `{{EmptyNameSpace}}` to an empty string (by commenting one code line and uncommenting the other) then proposed XPath expression `gesmes:Envelope/ns1:Cube/ns1:Cube/ns1:Cube` will not produce any result. I'm missing what should be the XPath expression with `http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref` being a default namespace - an XPath expression resulting in the same output as the original code currently results in. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I have prepared and I'm running the original code snippet in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) with the only additional reference set (via F4 -> Add...) to `System.XML.dll`...

Comment: @ShamilS: I have added a sample of what the XSLT should look like.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. Do you know why in XSL file I have to use a named namespace `xmlns:ns1 ='http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref` while in the source XML file to be transformed a default (unnamed) namespace `xmlns ='http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref'` is used? AFAIS I can use any name in XSL to name the source XML's default namespace, and then use that name in XPath expressions: where in XSL specs that naming (convention) is described/explained? It looks illogical for me, what is the reason of such a strange naming rules? Thank you.

Comment: @ShamilS: The XPath language just doesn't have a concept for namespaces without a prefix. Identifiers without a prefix in XPath are invariably considered to have no namespace. cf. e.g. [this posting](http://www.mail-archive.com/dom4j-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00961.html), which says: *in XPath its not possible to define the empty prefix to map to some
namespace URI*. It's just not supported by the XPath language, as opposed to the Xml language.

Comment: @ShamilS: As for your second question, you cannot just use any name in XSL to name the source Xml's default namespace; you can use any name to name any namespace. The only thing that must mach is the namespace URI; think of the prefix as an arbitrary placeholder that connects identifiers to namespace URIs. You could, for instance, leave your Xml document as it is, but replace the `gesmes` prefix in the XSLT with `blah` (in the `xmlns` attribute and all identifiers that use it), and things would still work as before.

Comment: Thank you. Subject issue solved and XSLT transformation stuff namespaces' usage is much clearer here now.